# ImageIO timeout javaj

Tags: java

I have an ImageIO read function that will be slower when the downloaded image is larger or on a slow server.  I there a way to have timeout on ImageIO?  Say max 10 seconds or I cancel the download?

```
BufferedImage  image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

The above function I want to complete in 10 seconds or cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You could call your read method in a Callable object and submit it with executor service to get Future object. something like:

```
public class MyImageCallable implments Callable..
    //..
    public void call()..
      //here your download image
```

On future object you could call get with 10 seconds time out and once time out reaches, your request get cancelled. Something like:

```
Future<..> f = executorService.submit(/* MyImageCallable object */);
try { 
    g.get.. 10 seconds..
} ..
```